# How to access DateAxisItem from a branch

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I ensured that there are no other pyqtgraph by removing existing installs:

```
rm -rf  ~idf/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyqtgraph*
```

I downloaded the branch with date-axis-item with

```
git clone -b date-axis-item https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git
```

and then ran inside the downloaded branch directory

```
python setup.py install
```

When I try to run this program it fails with

```
[idf@localhost python]$ python AxisExample1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AxisExample1.py", line 12, in <module>
    axis = pg.DateTimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DateTimeAxisItem'
```

**Note sure what I am doing wrong?**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Description of example
"""

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()

axis = pg.DateTimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
pw = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': axis})
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: DateTimeAxis')
pw.show()
pw.setXRange(1383960000, 1384020000) 

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: First of all your clone command does not have the correct branch. If you look into your cloned source code you wont find the DateTimeAxisItem module and therefore you get the mentioned error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git clone https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git

git checkout origin/date-axis-item

pip uninstall pyqtgraph

python setup.py install

and changing your example to:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Description of example
"""

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import numpy as np

pg.mkQApp()

axis = pg.DateAxisItem(orientation='bottom')
pw = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': axis})
pw.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: DateTimeAxis')
pw.show()
pw.setXRange(1383960000, 1384020000) 

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exe
```

should work.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git git checkout origin/date-axis-item
Too many arguments.

Comment: Hm it was not supposed to be a one-liner. Somehow it changed my post or i messed it up. First git clone https://github.com/3rdcycle/pyqtgraph.git and then git checkout origin/date-axis-item   . Same with the lib install commands. First remove the old pyqtgraph and then python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks the instructions are now accurate. On a linux machine at least, the last line should be QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()